# In loadrunner, parsing was not happened properly for the scripts replaying in HTML mode

Tags: loadrunner

In loadrunner, I recorded script in HTML mode by selected web_link, web_submit_form and do not record non-HTML resources. Like help document says, it won`t record non-HTML resources, but during replay it will parse the non-HTML resources from the parent request and send concurrent requests for those.

But when I replayed my scripts it's parsing only js,images and CSS files, its unable to parse other formats of non HTML resources like fonts.

Please let me know how to parse all non-HTML resources when I chooses above mentioned HTML mode options?

Comment: If it is not parsing and requesting correctly then you should leverage your support agreement and post this as a defect to HP to reconcile in the parser code.  Keep in mind that a font should have a cache setting of plus one year so it is not re-requested unnecessarily.   You may have parsed and downloaded it on the first page, but for all other pages it should not be necessary because of client side caching.

Comment: @JamesPulley, Thanks for the information, before reaching to HP support i would like to know if anyone faced such a problem.